# Boot issues with dual boot windows and ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am facing an issue when I did following. Initially my pc had Windows 7 ultimate x64 installed. Then I made it dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 x64. Everything used to work fine then.

Problem started when I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8 pro. After my upgrade I list grub loader. I was not getting any option to select OS. Then I googled the issue and somehow I do not remember exactly how, I fixed that issue. I am now getting OS option at boot time.

However sometimes usually after installing any updates in Ubuntu I do not see grub loader at boot. Sometimes it appears sometime is does not. I have figured out that this usually happens after Ubuntu update. To fix that issue I run boot-repair and repair system with recommended button. This solves the issue temporarily until Ubuntu update.

By ubuntu update I do not mean Ubuntu version upgrade, update means the security fixes and kind of stuff.

My recent boot repair log can be found at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5666240/

I am not that much technically familiar with linux machines so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen after any package update or just kernel updates? By the way, you have lots of kernels installed, it's fine to remove the older ones.

Comment: @grimpitch thanks, i will find a way to delete older kernels

Comment: @grimpitch: hi i tried to clean kernels using cleanup scripts but no luck, can you suggest me a way to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Via Windows tools, reduce your Windows partition from 75 to 74GB
2. Create a separate /boot partition in the 1GB free space as follow: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Comment: hi i tried to follow the steps mention in the given link but even after repeated tries i am unable to select the new created 1 G partition from boot-repair, any thoughts???

Comment: What is the URL provided by Boot-Repair?

Comment: hi, i formatted newly created drive with ext4 fs, then it was visible and I successfully relocated Grub loader. It also cleared old kernels :) that worked it seems, thanks